Need a shorter (better) method for this conic problem
The question- Consider the ellipse E: $16x^2+25y^2=400$. A light ray emerging from $P$(0,4) along the line $y=4$, gets reflected by a circle ($S$) of radius $\sqrt{65}$ units . The reflected ray ($L$)passes through (-3,0) and further gets reflected by the elliptical surface. The new reflected ray ($M$) passes through the original point (0,4). Find the coordinates of centre of the circle $S$.
My method- The ray ($M$) must pass through the second foci of the ellipse (3,0) as (-3,0) is first foci (reflection property).
Now we know the line $M$. We can obtain the point of intersection of ellipse and $M$ (call it point Q).
Now the equation of $L$ can be found out. The centre of circle must lie on the angle bisector ($N$) of $L$ and $y=4$ (Law of reflection). The point of intersection of y=4 and $L$ is say ($R$).
Once we obtain the slope of ($N$). Now we can apply parametric form of line from $R$ to get the centre.
My method is a bit too length and involves rough calculation. Anyone has a better method  (I am not able to take advantage of the fact that $PQR$ is a triangle)

A similar problem, not same, was given by my teacher in class today, and he expected us to do it using differential equations; and I'm still doing it.

Differential equations???

You must be in 11th standard. Next year you'll learn differential equations.

I know them, I am just exclaiming how can this question be related to calculus

Let $A=(-3,0)$ and $B=(3,0)$ be the foci of the ellipse. You can speed up a bit the computation of $Q$ using this result, valid for any focal chord:
$$
{1\over BQ}+{1\over BP}={2a\over b^2},
$$
where $a=5$ and $b=4$ are the semi-axes of the ellipse. As $BP=5$ one gets:
$$
BQ={40\over17}.
$$
The coordinates of $Q$ can then be found from $BQ/BP=8/17$:
$$
Q=B\left(1+{8\over17}\right)+P\left(-{8\over17}\right)=
\left({75\over17},-{32\over17}\right).
$$
But $BQ/BP=AQ/AR$ (by triangle similarity), hence we can find in the same way the coordinates of $R$:
$$
R=A\left(1+{17\over8}\right)+Q\left(-{17\over8}\right)=
\left(-{75\over4},4\right).
$$
Finally, to find the bisector of $\angle ARP$, let $E$ be the point where that bisector meets $AP$. We have
$$
{AE\over EP}={RA\over RP}={13\over15},
\quad\text{and}\quad
{AE\over AP}={13\over28}.
$$
Hence:
$$
E=A\left(1-{13\over28}\right)+P\left({13\over28}\right)=
\left(-{45\over28},{13\over7}\right).
$$
You can then compute $RE={15\over7}\sqrt{65}$ and find the coordinates of the center of the circle.

